# Move nVarChar data from one table to another and return PK to origin table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for advice on the best SQL Server 2008 R2 approach to move a reasonably high number of `nVarChar` data type rows from one table to another (actually there are a number of tables). In summary the objective is:

- `chapterOne` is a table that has a `nVarChar` column called `page_content`
- a new table called `RTE` has been created; this is the destination of `chapterOne.page_content` and other `nVarChar` data type rows from other tables
- first step is to rename `chapterOne` to `chapterOneSource` like so:

  ```
  exec sp_rename 'chapterOne ', 'chapterOneSource'
  ```
- next step is to add a foreign key to `chapterOneSource` like so:

  ```
  alter table chapterOneSource add pageContentID int null
  ```
- now I would like to move the data row by row from `chapterOne.page_content` to `RTE.page_content`. After each row is moved I would like to get the primary key which is `RTE.ID` and place this in the corresponding `chapterOneSource.pageContentID` column where the data came from. This is the part that I am having trouble with.

Does anybody have advice/help on the best approach for this using SQL Server?

- FYI after moving the data I would like to physically check both tables and see everything worked as expected. Then I will delete `chapterOne.page_content` and create a view.

Please note: I am not in a position to change the task. There is a good reason for why the high volume `nVarChar` columns need to be moved, its all about an over night sync where all of these type of columns need to be in the same table. Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: so let me get this summarized. You want to take data from one table and put it into another table and instead of data in first table just to have foreign key to the table where data now resides.

Comment: @saUce thank you for your reply.  yes thats exactley what I want to do. I am researching maybe a trigger after moving data from tableA to tableB to get the primary key from tableB back into a FK filed inn tableA.  But I am having a bit of trouble wit it.  Any assistance would be excellent

Comment: Does `chapterOne` have any PK column? That would make this a lot easier - just insert the key and the `page_content` columns, and update by joining back with the key.

Comment: Yes its called course_matid and the foreign key which will link it to RTE is called pageContentID

Answer (score 0):

If this is just one time move I would do it in the following way.

In your table where you have the data I would add new column that will house foreign key. Once that is done write the query to update table to generate foreign keys. After that just take the foreign key column and data and move it to new table. Once that is done and you verified the data is correct you can drop the data column from first table. I will post code tomorrow how to do it all with a query.

```
INSERT INTO ChapterOneSource
SELECT  c.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS MyNewFK
FROM ChapterOne AS c;

INSERT INTO RTE
SELECT c.FK, c.DATA
From ChapterOneSource AS c;

ALTER TABLE ChapterOneSource
DROP COLUMN Data
```

By Using `Row_Number()` I created new unique number that will be your future FK. This way instead of trying to figure out which row to update later with FK you just move FK to PK field and drop `page_content` column. Later on you will just need to add data to your RTE table, generate new PK by using `IDENTITY` column and just place that PK as FK into ChapterOneSource